# How to fix python basic math operations returning as address codes?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I created a simple python calculator using functions for *basic mathematical operations* (eg: divide, add). It runs without errors but it shows some kind of an 'address code' as the final output without showing the actual calculation.

example output:

```
0x00401978
```

I was trying to output the calculation as "calculaion = xxx" using `print("calculation =" + str(add))`.
but as I got these *weird* outputs, I removed all the strings and tried to output only the calculation. But the problem remained. This is that minimal code-

```
def add (a,b) :
    calc = a + b
    return calc
def subs (a,b) :
    calc = a - b
    return calc
def mul (a,b) :
    calc = a * b
    return calc
def divi (a,b) :
    calc = a/b
    return calc

print (" Select operation. \n 1.Add \n 2.Substract \n 3.Multiply \n 4.divide ")

choice = int (input (" Enter choice (1/2/3/4) "))
a = int (input (" Enter first number: "))
b = int (input (" Enter second number : "))

if choice == 1 :
    print (add)
elif choice == 2 :
    print (subs)
elif choice == 3 :
    print (mul)
elif choice == 4 :
    print (divi)
else:
    print ("Ooops my love. Wrong number")
```

Full Output with the *weird* result-

```
 Select operation. 
 1.Add 
 2.Substract 
 3.Multiply 
 4.divide 
 Enter choice (1/2/3/4) 2
 Enter first number: 20
 Enter second number : 10
<function subs at 0x030AE198>
```

I just need the output to be "Calculation = XXXX" and the operations must be done in functions. (XXXX is the result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the method. You are printing the memory location/repr of the method.

Each of your ifs should be

```
if choice == 1 :
    print (add(a,b))
elif choice == 2 :
    print (subs(a,b))
elif choice == 3 :
    print (mul(a,b))
elif choice == 4 :
    print (divi(a,b))
```

Or remove the print

```
if choice == 1 :
    add(a,b)
elif choice == 2 :
    subs(a,b)
elif choice == 3 :
    mul(a,b)
elif choice == 4 :
    divi(a,b)
```

A very simplistic example of what you're doing:

```
def test_method():
    print("I've been called!")

test_method
test_method()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way view other memory addresses of other data like the strings that I'm printing?